# Distribute points of loop evenly with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I added a method to an addon to create a ring around an object by drawing a line which is then projected onto the object like this:

[image]

The algorithm is not perfect but works. The only thing that is missing is to distribute the vertices of the ring evenly (same distances between the vertices), I think it could be done in a post processing step.

Does somebody know an approach or has an algorithm for that?

Comment: The looptools addon has an operator for that, it's under `bpy.ops.mesh.looptools_circle` maybe you can copy the behavior ?

Comment: I think the ring is draw by gpu module with random geometry (like all triangle). Draw circle dot in opengl is hard, can consider draw square.

Comment: is your ring always a perfect circle?

Comment: @Chris No. I draw a line then a circle with this diameter and then project the point onto the mesh in the direction of a center that I calculated before.

Comment: @Gorgious Ah ok thx, will have a look. But it is not a perfect circle, just a ring, but will see.

Comment: @Jayanam oh in this case you want the space tools I think. `bpy.ops.mesh.looptools_space`  Check out the tools in the n panel in edit mode after enabling the looptools addon https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tav8R.png

Comment: Since moving the vertices around changes the original shape, a better result than loop tools space could be achieved, but it's not trivial. I think machine learning could be used here, to find the most optimal arrangement of vertices, given some formulas calculating score based on the number of vertices (either the lower the better or the closer to x the better), as well as minimum, maximum, average (mean etc.) distances from the original ring. Perhaps also the distances between vertices could affect score if you're willing to give them some tolerance.